# Cross domain authentication yii framework and AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, yii

I have a large web application it contains 2 parts backend and frontend . Backend is based on yiiboilerplate and frontend is based on angularjs .And I have placed those on different domains , so my http request from frontend goes as cross domain requests. My question is . how to implement user  authentication  via cross domain request ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you aware of CORS? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-cors.html

Comment: not at all, only basic knowledge

Answer (score 0):

After hard research I find solution . (Token based authentication). without using cookies.